# authorize.net hello world Charge Credit Card ERROR : Invalid response

Tags: php, authorize.net

Trying to get the Hello World example for Authorize.net to work

Composer is installed here is json. almost identical to their example.

```
{
"require": {
    "symfony/console": "^3.3",
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "authorizenet/authorizenet": ">=1.9.3"    
}
}
```

the following was cut & pasted from ssh

```
>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

The only thing I've changed in the Hello World PHP example is my sandbox login ID and transaction key and the path to vendor/autoload.php.

What am I missing here to get this example to return something other than

Charge Credit Card ERROR : Invalid response

Comment: I changed the example to the one provided in github sample-code-php-master.zip   and now my error is Transaction Failed Error Code : E00003 Error Message : The 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:name' element is invalid - The value 'F9lTBd40K839Bucfq3Sz_DKqW2j2Xo7i' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is greater than the MaxLength value.

Comment: According to their developer website CODE: E00003

EXPLANATION: An error occurred while parsing the XML request.

Comment: I updated the code yet again, from the example code here:  http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions ,  and now am getting this error, which the error code lookup tool says in an invalid error code!   Transaction Failed Error Code : E00124 Error Message : The provided access token is invalid

Comment: ps. running the samples here in the broswer interface works http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions  it is only when I try and run a php file that I get the error

Comment: The basic Hello World example is now working, https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/ , but the other is not.  Not sure why.  Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem was rather simple.  Posting solution here to pay it forward.  First, this all you need for a basic working composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "symfony/console": "^3.3",
    "authorizenet/authorizenet": ">=1.9.3"    
}
}
```

You probably don't even need symphony. By the way, I'm running php 5.6 and TLS 1.2, which are required.

Second, there is a scope issue in the example code.  Here are the first few lines of the charge credit card example code, which works in the authorize.net browser sandbox fine.

```
function chargeCreditCard($amount)
{

$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
$merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);
```

Here is what I changed it to in my php script that DID NOT work.

```
    function chargeCreditCard(){

    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName($AuthorizeLoginID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey($AuthorizeTransKey);
```

Here is what I changed it to that DOES work.

```
    function chargeCreditCard(){

    global $AuthorizeLoginID, $AuthorizeTransKey;

    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName($AuthorizeLoginID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey($AuthorizeTransKey);
```

Kinda mad at myself for not seeing the scope issue with the credentials sooner, but I eventually figured it out by process of elimination.

Comment: run composer update to ensure you have the latest code, and update the sdk files